# Where should i dispose a sub form

Tags: c#

I have FormA that creates another form, FormB, when a button is pressed.

Where should i dispose FormB.
Is it OK to dispose FormB in FormA Closing event?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When FormB is closed (with the `.Close` method) it will be disposed so you don't need to manually call the `.Dispose` method.

Comment: What if user closes FormA (clicking on the X button on the top-right) without closing FormB? Will all resources be freed?

Answer (score 0):

When FormB is closed by clicking the X or other possiblities where it is just hidden it is not disposed. If that form in that instance occurs often, dispose it when in FormA or application exit. If that form is not opened that often you can even dispose in in the click-event-handler of the button. There it is possible with the `using` keyword.

```
using(FormB b = new FormB())
{
    if(b.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {...} else {...}
}
```

Of course this is only possible when it is shown modal.

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
```

you can see this in form designer.cs file it will be called when a form is closed so no need to worry about dispose

Answer (score 0):

[from msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close%28VS.90%29.aspx)

> The two conditions when a form is not
>   disposed on Close is when (1) it is
>   part of a multiple-document interface
>   (MDI) application, and the form is not
>   visible; and (2) you have displayed
>   the form using ShowDialog. In these
>   cases, you will need to call Dispose
>   manually to mark all of the form's
>   controls for garbage collection.

It's better to use using:

```
using (var modalForm = new FormB())
{
    modalAddUser.ShowDialog();
}
```